# Python парсинг данных теряются данные

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, парсер

Занимаюсь изучением PyThon, скажите пожалуйста, почему в print(crypto) респонсится только текст, а не JSON? Вот код:

```
import urllib.request, json
from pprint import pprint

resource = urllib.request.urlopen('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR')

result = json.loads(resource.read().decode())

for crypto in result:
    pprint(crypto)
```

Comment: в print ничего вообще не может "респонситься". что выводится на печать при print(result)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в `result` находится словарь, а при итерации по словарю будут выданы ключи словаря.

Можно вывести ключ-значение, если использовать метод словаря `items`:

```
import json
import urllib.request

resource = urllib.request.urlopen('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR')
result = json.loads(resource.read().decode())

for crypto, ccy in result.items():
    print(crypto, ccy)
# BTC {'USD': 18566.58, 'EUR': 15675.4}
# ETH {'USD': 507.55, 'EUR': 428.54}
```

**PS.**

Вместо `items` можно так:

```
for crypto in result:
    print(crypto, result[crypto])
```